# APK build error xamarin exited with code 3

Tags: xamarin

I am using Xamarin visual studio 2015, new to xamarin visual studio, when i tried to creat an apk file got this issue as follows,

The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\mono-symbolicate" store-symbols "bin\Release\Bat.Bat.apk.mSYM" "obj\Release\android/assets"" exited with code 3.

kindly suggest me how to fix this.

Suresh G

Comment: Exit code 3 is `The system cannot find the path specified.` Does `mono-symbolicate` exist at that location? Try setting Debug Information on your Release build from `Symbols-Only` to `None` to bypass storing the mSYM files until you can review/verify your installation...